# android:clearTaskOnLaunch not working

Tags: android, task

For some reason android:clearTaskOnLaunch does not seem to be working for me.

This is what I have in my manifest:

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:icon="@drawable/i" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MeuhedetThemeNoTitle"  
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" 
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>  
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="" 
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"  
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"/>
```

The first is a splash screen which also does a little bit of work and then moves over to the second activity. That is the main menu.

I have managed to get all other activities to "die" by using android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" on all of them.

However, once the application has been run once the splash screen doesn't come up again next time I start it and the activity "MainScreenActivity" is immediately launched.
This happens when I press the home screen on my device.

Comment: This attribute is meaningful only for activities that start a new task

Comment: @SamirMangroliya How can you be sure?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correct then, when you press home button activity doesn't get destroyed, it's paused, when you try to launch application again, android doesn't launch app, it resumes the last activity from the stack.

Comment: I thought it was a problem on when created from Eclipse. I tried doing via apk file and it worked a couple of times and then stopped working again. Weird.

Comment: @theblitz Android OS decides by its own when the time to kill the app. If app doesn't sit in memory launch will start from launch activity. Running app from Eclipse "always"(if code changes were made) install fresh instance of app, it "always" be a new launch. Apparently several times when you launched installed apk it wasn't a paused process (fresh start), other times it was (resume state from the stack).

Comment: If you tap back button until all activities are popped out of stack, then next launch will be a new one.

Answer (score 0):

> This attribute is meaningful only for activities that start a new task (the root activity); it's ignored for all other activities in the task. [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear)

Based on your manifest file you can set this flag only on your MainActivity.

Comment: Please elaborate on this. I'm having a similar problem. When our app crashes for any reason, it restarts the previous activity which has a bunch of null data. This is really annoying. All I want to have happen is to have my app crash gracefully and restart from the beginning! How do I know and set 'activities that start a new task'? Please be specific with what needs to be added to the AndroidManifest and activity class(es).

Answer (score -3):

put I tried setting clearTaskOnLaunch="true"  in the Application section please :) i think it will work

Comment: @ikrami What are you talking about?